# How to track whether the order confirmation mail is loaded in email queue or not

Tags: database, email

I have a problem which **order confirmation mail sent twice.**
I debug the cron.php file and it works good. My ecommerce send well all kind of email automatically but order confirmation mail.

I realize that it's not from cron job and it seems like **order information is dupicated in email queue** based on database problem.

What do you think of that? I'm really freaking out for 1 week.
And could you let me know the which php file manage the order information?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

When order confirmation email received, please make sure the `email_sent` flag in `sales_flat_order` is `1` for your increment_id , if it is M2 then check in `sales_order`.

If this flag value still remain `0` then the order number won't removed from the email queue.

Comment: "email_sent flag" in "sales_flat_order" of every record is 1 ! And how could i do on next level?

Comment: Please take a look on the following options,
1. Put a log in "queueNewOrderEmail" and "sendNewOrderEmail" in this function in Sales module and make sure how many times this function called (if you are putting log in core Sales module please remove after the debug)
2. Then please verify "core_email_queue" table to make sure how many line items for your order number.

Comment: I fixed it. when our site was downgraded, the methods like sendmail, send queuenewmail are overwritten by newest version! Thanks a lot !